# Can Physalis be propagated in any way other than seed?

Tags: propagation

How can [Physalis, or Cape Gooseberry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physalis), be propagated using a method other than seed propagation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another way - they're perennial, and can be divided during the dormant season, which is, in the UK, winter and early spring, so about now would be good. Always assuming you're not under 6 feet of water, that is, given the weather we've had this year...

Answer (score 4):

You can also apparently grow them from stem cuttings.  The link below from the rare fruit society says to use semi-mature material from the middle of the one year old shoot, and to dust it with rooting hormone.

http://www.crfg.org/pubs/ff/cape-gooseberry.html